# Statsd installation on Ubuntu 14.04 issue. Unable to start service after installation

Tags: 14.04

I'm a relative newbie to running ubuntu, but I have followed along with Justin Ellingwood's fantastic tutorials for getting graphite and statsd setup to run on Ubuntu 14.04. (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-statsd-to-collect-arbitrary-stats-for-graphite-on-ubuntu-14-04)

I have completed the installation of statsd as per the tute, but I cannot get the service to start! Whenever I run sudo service statsd start it will say it's successful and give it a process number, but then I run a sudo service statsd status command it shows the status statsd stop/waiting. Anyone know what I might be able to do to track this issue down?

Comment: Check if there are errors in log file. `ls -lrt /var/log /var/log/upstart` after start command, to find out changed log file.

Answer (score 0):

I would go over the config files again.

```
sudo nano /etc/statsd/localConfig.js
```

Can also try and restart these. Wait a few seconds between each.

```
sudo service statsd stop
sudo service carbon-cache stop      
sudo service carbon-cache start
sudo service statsd start
```

Still having problems look to see if it really is not running.

Run this command to take a look at what is running.

```
sudo netstat -nlp
```

If it is running you will see ip:port under Local Address.

```
Statsd 0.0.0.0:8126, 0.0.0.0:8125 
carbon 0.0.0.0:2003, 0.0.0.0:2004
```